# Algorithm for "pick the number up game"

Tags: algorithm, permutation, puzzle

I'm struggling to get some solution, but I have no idea for that.

RobotA and RobotB who choose a permutation of the N numbers to begin with. RobotA picks first, and they pick alternately. Each turn, robots only can pick any one remaining number from the permutation. When the remaining numbers form an increasing sequence, the game finishes. The robot who picked the last turn (after which the sequence becomes increasing) wins the game.

Assuming both play optimally , who wins?

***Example 1:***

```
 The original sequence is 1 7 3. 
 RobotA wins by picking 7, after which the sequence is increasing 1 3.
```

***Example 2:***

```
 The original sequence is 8 5 3 1 2.
 RobotB wins by selecting the 2, preventing any increasing sequence.
```

Is there any known algorithm to solve that? Please give me any tips or ideas of where to look at would be really thankful!

Comment: Sorry for posting with no real solution, but I find that if you keep the English basic, more people understand. Having English as a 2nd language, I also feel the need to use big words like "permutation", but simply saying "re-arranging" it makes it easier to read and understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @user85569 I disagree. No reason to dumb down the language. Especially when permutation is a common word in Mathematics and Computer Science.

Comment: @user85569, permutation is a standard mathematical term. It can't be replaced by re-arranging.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich I wasn't taught math or computer science in English. So I had to look-up the word in Google to know what he was trying to say. It hinders the process as I'm sure a lot of other people don't speak English as their first language, nor was taught in it. Was a suggestion to make things easier to understand for everyone... since this is the internet...

Comment: @Wisdom's Wind N just is input condition , when the sequence is 8 5 3 1 2 , means N is 5.

Comment: No. What is the max possible N ?

Comment: @Wisdom's Wind   i think whatever the max possible N,  but need to guarantee no repeatable element in the sequence.

Comment: Let me explain, I can give you a solution, but it takes O(N!) time. If it's ok, I can write it.

Comment: I still don't get the game. Neither sequence is a permutation. Do you mean the robots each choose distinct numbers up to some total length? If so, then surely parity matters. Can you please explain more clearly how the game works and what the termination condition is?

Comment: @PengOne - I think what he meant to say is that the robots **initially** start with a permutation of `{1, ..., N}`. His examples do not present the original sequences (the permutations), but the sequences after a certain number of steps in the game (so some numbers are missing, but they were initially permutations).

Comment: @IVlad This still makes no sense to me. Are you saying that he pulls numbers from a permutation until the remaining sequence is increasingly ordered? If so, then the solution depends on the original permutation. An actual example or clear exposition would be helpful.

Comment: @PengOne - yes, that is how I understand it. You are given a permutation, and players `A` and `B` take turns removing numbers from it, `A` going first. Whoever makes it so the remaining numbers are in increasing order wins. For example: `1 4 3 2` => `A` removes `1`, and whatever `B` removes after that, `A` will win in the next move. So if both play optimally, `A` will definitely win.

Answer (score 4):

Given a sequence `w` of distinct numbers, let `N(w)` be the length of `w` and let `L(w)` be the length of the longest increasing subsequence in `w`. For example, if

```
w = 3 5 8 1 4
```

then `N(w) = 5` and `L(w) = 3`.

The game ends when `L(w) = N(w)`, or, equivalently, `N(w) - L(w) = 0`.

Working the game backwards, if on RobotX's turn `N(w) - L(w) = 1`, then the optimal play is to remove the unique letter not in a longest increasing subsequence, thereby winning the game.

For example, if `w = 1 7 3`, then `N(w) = 3` and `L(w) = 2` with a longest increasing subsequence being `1 3`. Removing the `7` results in an increasing sequence, ensuring that the player who removed the `7` wins.

Going back to the previous example, `w = 3 5 8 1 4`, if either `1` or `4` is removed, then for the resulting permutation `u` we have `N(u) - L(u) = 1`, so the player who removed the `1` or `4` will certainly lose to a competent opponent. However, any other play results in a victory since it forces the next player to move to a losing position. Here, the optimal play is to remove any of `3`, `5`, or `8`, after which `N(u) - L(u) = 2`, but after the next move `N(v) - L(v) = 1`.

Further analysis along these lines should lead to an optimal strategy for either player.

---

The nearest mathematical game that I do know is the Monotone Sequence Game. In a monotonic sequence game, two players alternately choose elements of a sequence from some fixed ordered set (e.g. `1,2,...,N`). The game ends when the resulting sequence contains either an ascending subsequence of length `A` or a descending one of length `D`. This game has its origins with a theorem of Erdos and Szekeres, and a nice exposition can be found in [MONOTONIC SEQUENCE GAMES](http://www.math.msu.edu/~sagan/Papers/Old/msg.pdf), and this [slide presentation](http://www.mth.msu.edu/~sagan/Slides/msg.pdf) by Bruce Sagan is also a good reference.

If you want to know more about game theory in general, or these sorts of games in particular, then I strong recommend Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays by Berlekamp, Conway and Guy. Volume 3, I believe, addresses these sorts of games.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a [Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) problem.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to go. It's going to be very slow and very hard to implement such that the game play is optimal.

Comment: @IVlad Do you have a better suggestion? Minimax, or alpha-beta pruning, are the standard ways to explore game trees like this.

Comment: @NickJohnson - no it's not. It's only standard for games that have no efficient mathematical solution. The standard approach is to try to find a mathematical approach using game theory. You wouldn't use minimax for the nim game, would you? The problem looks like it has one, but no, I don't have an actual solution yet.

Comment: @IVlad, I was also not sure whether this is a actual minimax. That's why I have not said it's minimax, I said it looks like a minimax. it sounded to me that minimax could be a possible solution. And yes, I also don't have a perfect solution.

Comment: @IVlad Sure, but I'm not convinced it has one, and you haven't demonstrated otherwise. You should save criticism until you have a concrete alternative to offer.

Comment: @Nick Johnson - it was more of an opinion than criticism since I didn't downvote. If this is assigned in a class or asked in an interview, I think the expected answer is not something like minimax. If you want to see if a student/interviewee knows minimax, there are better questions to ask. And the "optimal play" part is a dead giveaway, in my opinion. Minimax implementations can be very smart, but I haven't heard of an optimal one yet. I just think it's a wrong path to take here, that's all.

Comment: And why should I even save criticism if I don't have anything better? Maybe my criticism will help others come up with something. It certainly doesn't hurt anything or anyone as long as it's constructive and I have arguments.

Comment: @IVlad Minimax and related algorithms (alpha-beta and refinements thereof) are exactly what's used to determine optimal play. In fact, the whole foundation of minimax is "act in the way that you minimize the worst consequences of your opponent's actions", which is precisely what optimal play is.

Comment: @Nick Johnson - Minimax use a rating function to assign scores to a part of the game tree, then picks the move to make based on these scores. Since the game tree is usually very large (yes, pruning methods do exists, but the game tree is still usually too large to fully explore), minimax will never play optimally, because it's very hard to guarantee this function will work optimally with the information available to it. Try to solve games like nim with minimax. Then solve them mathematically, compare with your minimax, and see which one is really optimal.

Comment: @IVlad If you exhaustively search the game tree - the only way to play a game without a trivial solution optimally - minimax/alpha-beta results in optimal play. It's only when you have to limit your search depth and make approximations that that's not the case. I'm not suggesting using minimax on a problem that has a trivial solution, but you haven't demonstrated that that's the case here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is more fast solution for this task. I will think.
But I can give you an idea of solution with O(N! * N^2) complexity.

At first,  note that picking number from N-permutation is equivalent to the following:

1. Pick number from N-permutation. Let's it was number X.
2. Reassign numbers using rule:

1 = 1

2 = 2

...

X-1 = X-1

X = Nothing, it's gone.

X+1 = X

...

N = N - 1

And you get permutation of N-1 numbers.

Example:

1 5 6 4 2 3

Pick 2

1 5 6 4 3

Reassign

1 4 5 3 2

Let's use this one as move, instead just picking. It's easy too see that games are equivalent, player A wins in this game for some permutation if and only if it wins in original.

Let's give a code to all permutations of N numbers, N-1 numbers, ... 2 numbers.

Define F(x) -> {0; 1} (where x is a permutation code) is function which is 1 when current

player wins, and 0 if current player fails. Easy to see F(1 2 .. K-1 K) = 0.

F(x) = 1 if there is at least on move which transforms x to y, and F(y) = 0.

F(x) = 0 if for any move which transforms x to y, F(y) = 1.

So you can use recursion with memorization to compute:

```
Boolean F(X)
{
    Let K be length of permutation with code X.
    if you already compute F for argument X return previously calculated result;
    if X == 1 2 .. K return 0;
    Boolean result = 0;
    for i = 1 to K do
    {
         Y code of permutation get from X by picking number on position i.
         if (F(y) == 0)
         {
             result = 1;   
             break;
         }
    }
    Store result as F(X);
    return result;
}
```

For each argument we will compute this function only once. There is 1! permutations of length 1, 2! permutations of length 2 .. N! permutations of length N. For permutation length K, we need to do O(K) operation to compute. So complexity will be O(1*1! + 2*2! + .. N*N!) =<= O(N! * N^2) = O(N! * N^2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Python code for Wisdom's Wind's algorithm. It prints out wins for RobotA.

```
import itertools

def moves(p):
    if tuple(sorted(p)) == p:
        return
    for i in p:
        yield tuple(j - (j > i) for j in p if j != i)

winning = set()

for n in range(6):
    for p in itertools.permutations(range(n)):
        if not winning.issuperset(moves(p)):
            winning.add(p)

for p in sorted(winning, key=lambda q: (len(q), q)):
    print(p)
```